# Merge two dataframes on index, get rid of key_0

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two dataframes by the index columns. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['red', 'red', 'red']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [1, 2, 2]})

df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=df1.index, right_on=df2.index)
print(df.head())

   key_0    a  b
0      0  red  1
1      1  red  2
2      2  red  2
```

The result has an unwanted column `key_0`. Question: How do I get rid of this column (without any drops after the merge)?

Comment: Why merge? You need: `pd.concat([df1, df2], 1)` .

Comment: I simplified the example. If `df2` would be longer than `df1`, I would get rows with `NaNs`. Hence, I wanted the left-merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of treating the index-columns as regular columns, I was able to get rid of the `key_0` by using the keywords `left_index` and `right_index`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df.head())

     a  b
0  red  1
1  red  2
2  red  2
```